# Azure access token for all files in sub directory

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I have a secure Azure Blob set up as follows:

```
ContainerName > SubDirectory/FileName

E.g., /Photos/0000001/pic.png
```

Some of these sub directories contain thousands of files that all need to be rendered to a web page. Since the Blob is secured, I'm currently getting an access token for each individual file using `GetSharedAccessSignature(...)`.

Is there a way I could instead get a single token that would grant access to all files within the sub directory ("/0000001/"), or is what I'm currently doing considered best practice?

Answer (score 4):

You can only get `Shared Access Signature` for a `blob container` or for a `single blob`, but you are **NOT** able to get `Shared Access Signature` for a `blob virtual directory`, since directory isn't a real concept in Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I missed this, but here's how to get an access token for a directory:

```
var blob = storageService.Context.Container.ListBlobs().FirstOrDefault();

var policy =
    new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)
    };

blob.Container.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
```

Comment: This would give access to the entire blob container, not the subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions support directory level access if hierarchical namespace is activated i.e. data lake. See [MS Docs: Service SAS support for directory scoped access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#service-sas-support-for-directory-scoped-access).